# Рефакторинг API (JS)

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Написал такой код, который взаимодействует со Star Wars API (SWAPI)- принимает от пользователя значение инпута и ищет совпадения на сайте. Селектом можно выбрать конкретный тип поиска-корабль, персонаж или планету, но получился длинный, страшный код. Нужно написать такую функцию, которая будет принимать как аргумент select.value, и в зависимости от значения подставлять нужную разметку. Данные для этой разметки подставлять из объекта с объектами (прошу прощения за тавтологию).

```js
let searchButton = document.querySelector('.searchButton');
let search = document.querySelector('.search');
let searchResult = document.querySelector('.search_result');
let name = document.querySelector('.name');
let height = document.querySelector('.height');
let mass = document.querySelector('.mass');
let birth_year = document.querySelector('.birth_year');
let films_count = document.querySelector('.films_count');
let select = document.querySelector('.select');
let div1 = document.querySelector('.div1');
let div2 = document.querySelector('.div2');
let div3 = document.querySelector('.div3');
let div4 = document.querySelector('.div4');
let div5 = document.querySelector('.div5');

let response;

window.onload = function () {
    select = document.querySelector('.select');
    let api = "https://swapi.dev/api/";
    let url = api + select.value + "/?search=";
    url += search.value;
    getRevenueByID = async (arr) => {
        let request = await fetch(url);

        if (request.ok) { // если HTTP-статус в диапазоне 200-299
            response = await request.json();
        } else {
            alert("Ошибка HTTP: " + response.status);
        }

        if (response.count == 0) {
            alert("К сожалению, данные не получены по запросу: " + url);
            return;
        }

        // alert("Найдено персонажей:" + response.count);
        for (let i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++) {
            let l1 = document.createElement('li');
            l1.setAttribute('name', i)
            l1.textContent = response.results[i].name;
            searchResult.appendChild(l1);
        }
    };
};


searchButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    while (searchResult.firstChild) {
        searchResult.removeChild(searchResult.firstChild);
    }
    if (search.value != '') {
        onload();
        getRevenueByID();
        search.value = '';
    } else {
        alert('Пустая строка');
    }
});

searchResult.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
    let target = event.target;
    if (target.className != 'search_result') {
        let index = target.getAttribute('name');
        if (select.value == 'people') {
            div2.innerHTML = 'Рост:<span class="height"></span>';
            div3.innerHTML = 'Вес:<span class="mass"></span>';
            div4.innerHTML = 'Год рождения:<span class="birth_year"></span>';
            div5.innerHTML = 'В скольки фильмах появлялся:<span class="films_count"></span>';
            name = document.querySelector('.name');
            height = document.querySelector('.height');
            mass = document.querySelector('.mass');
            birth_year = document.querySelector('.birth_year');
            films_count = document.querySelector('.films_count');
            name.textContent = response.results[index].name;
            height.textContent = response.results[index].height;
            mass.textContent = response.results[index].mass;
            birth_year.textContent = response.results[index].birth_year;
            films_count.textContent = response.results[index].films.length;
        }
        if (select.value == 'planets') {
            div2.innerHTML = 'День(часов):<span class="height"></span>';
            div3.innerHTML = 'Год(дней):<span class="mass"></span>';
            div4.innerHTML = 'Ландшафт:<span class="birth_year"></span>';
            div5.innerHTML = 'Популяция:<span class="films_count"></span>';
            name = document.querySelector('.name');
            height = document.querySelector('.height');
            mass = document.querySelector('.mass');
            birth_year = document.querySelector('.birth_year');
            films_count = document.querySelector('.films_count');
            name.textContent = response.results[index].name;
            height.textContent = response.results[index].rotation_period;
            mass.textContent = response.results[index].orbital_period;
            birth_year.textContent = response.results[index].terrain;
            films_count.textContent = response.results[index].population;
        }
        if (select.value == 'starships') {
            div2.innerHTML = 'Модель:<span class="height"></span>';
            div3.innerHTML = 'Стоимость в кредитах:<span class="mass"></span>';
            div4.innerHTML = 'Пассажиров:<span class="birth_year"></span>';
            div5.innerHTML = 'Длинна:<span class="films_count"></span>';
            name = document.querySelector('.name');
            height = document.querySelector('.height');
            mass = document.querySelector('.mass');
            birth_year = document.querySelector('.birth_year');
            films_count = document.querySelector('.films_count');
            name.textContent = response.results[index].name;
            height.textContent = response.results[index].model;
            mass.textContent = response.results[index].cost_in_credits;
            birth_year.textContent = response.results[index].passengers;
            films_count.textContent = response.results[index].length;
        }
    }
});

//данные для разметки
var dateToInsert = {
    people: {
        height: "рост",
        mass: "вес",
        birth_year: "год рождения",
        films_count: "в каком количестве фильмов появлялся",
    },
    starships: {
        model: "модель",
        cost_in_credits: "стоимость в кредитах",
        passengers: "пассажиров",
        length: "длина",
    },
    planets: {
        rotation_period: "день (часов)",
        orbital_period: "год (дней)",
        terrain: "ландшафт",
        population: "население",
    }
}
// необходимая функция
function toggleMarking () {

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Клиент и сервер</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body class="content">
  <div class="searchBlock">
    <label class="searchLabel">
      <label>Поиск персонажа: <input type="text" class="search"></label>
    </label>
    <select class="select">
      <option class="person">people</option>
      <option class="ship">starships</option>
      <option class="planet">planets</option>
    </select>
    <button class="searchButton">Найти</button>
    <ul class="search_result"></ul>
  </div>
  <div class="person_data">
    <div class="div1">Имя: <span class="name"></span></div>
    <div class="div2">Рост: <span class="height"></span></div>
    <div class="div3">Вес: <span class="mass"></span></div>
    <div class="div4">Год рождения: <span class="birth_year"></span></div>
    <div class="div5">В каком количестве фильмов появлялся: <span class="films_count"></span></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Вероятно, лучше подготовить DOM для отображения каждого типа данных заранее и скрывать ненужные чем каждый раз полностью перестраивать dom

Comment: vp_arth, идея хорошая, согласен, но по стилям не получится-блоки же будут друг под другом, пустого места много. Задание учебное-сказали делать функцию, так как 
div2.innerHTML = 'День(часов):<span class="height"></span>';
            div3.innerHTML = 'Год(дней):<span class="mass"></span>';
            div4.innerHTML = 'Ландшафт:<span class="birth_year"></span>';
            div5.innerHTML = 'Популяция:<span class="films_count"></span>';
часто повторяющийся блок, где меняется только первое слово